# AngularJS ng-repeat Table with 3 Jsons

Tags: angularjs, json, foreach, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make a table in AngularJS

Its a vacation planer.

**It should look like so:**

```
              day   day   day   day   day   day   day   day   day   day   day   day
employeename color color color color color color color color color color color color
employeename color color color color color color color color color color color color
employeename color color color color color color color color color color color color
```

I get the days, the employename and the color foreach day and each employee in 3 different Jsons.

**Employee json :**

```
[{
  name: "John Doe",
  short: "JD",
  group: "J's Group",
  degree_short: "CEO",
  degree: "Chief Executive Officer",
  department: "Management"
 }]
```

**The Days Json :**

```
     [{
       weekday: "Fr",
       day: "25",
       date: 1450998000000
       }]
```

**And my Vacations Json :**

```
     [{
       short: "twi",
       first_date: 1468965600000,
       end_date: 1468965600000,
       reason: 1
     }]
```

The Problem is, that NG-Repeat only Repeat one Json emidatly but I need 
it like :

```
  angular.forEach(staff, function (users, key) {
        angular.forEach(days, function (dates, key) {
            angular.forEach(vacations, function (vacation, key) {
                if (holidays.krzl == users.krzl) {
                    if (holidays.first_date <= dates.date && holidays.end_date >= dates.date) {
                        if (holidays.reason == '0') {
                            return color = "grey";
                        } else if (holidays.reason == '1') {
                            return color = "green";
                        } else if (holidays.reason == '2') {
                            return color = "red";
                        } else if (holidays.reason == '3') {
                            return color = "blue";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But I cant simply generate a table with echos like in PHP..

Has anyone an idea ?

Edit : Here is a Plunk with my current status : https://plnkr.co/edit/dt0s4WAc1foln9jOsK3f?p=preview

Comment: Why are you not doing the processing of the data  in the controller or a service and then using ng-repeat on the processed array?

Comment: I tried it alredy but its deformated. I wrote a filter also. Nothing works for me.

Comment: Why don't you create a plunk to explain your problem clearly. It's a mess right now.

Comment: well there are possible ways, easiest way is to work around with custom directives.make a directive for those and and then you can loop over them. That is better and fast.And In would recommend you to please make a plnker for that.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dt0s4WAc1foln9jOsK3f?p=preview Here is a plunk with my current status

Comment: I need for each cell a different color and for some only an empty cell.